# .htaccess rewrite url with two variables

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem with my `.htaccess` rewrite rule (I'm new at this, so probably it's an easy thing)

I have a URL that is:

```
http://www.example.com/film-al-cinema/?titolo=Ghost+in+the+Shell&id=315837
```

So I have the title of the movie inside the first variable `titolo=""` and the ID of the movie in the second variable `id=""`.

I want the URL to look like

```
http://www.example.com/film-al-cinema/Ghost+in+the+Shell/315837
```

I've tried to change the htaccess file with this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^film-al-cinema/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ film-al-cinema/?titolo=$1&id=$2 [R]
</IfModule>
```

but this redirects me to a 404 page

**EDIT**

I'm working on Wordpress so the `/film-al-cinema/` is a Wordpress Page

**EDIT 2**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^film-al-cinema/([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$  /index.php?page_id=21016&titolo=$1&id=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: I thin there is already rewriting rules for film-al-cinema

Comment: film-al-cinema is not a directory but it is a wordpress page so I think it is possible?

Comment: If `film-al-cinema` is not an existing directory, how does wordpress map on ` http://www.websitename.com/film-al-cinema/?...`? Or even better: where is wordpress' index.php located? Are there more rules in your .htaccess installed by wordpress?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I didn't understand, sorry. This is the url if you want to check http://www.pulpcorn.com/film-al-cinema/?titolo=Ghost+in+the+Shell&id=315837

Comment: Ok, pulpcom.com is a WP site. You want to map one particular content page of it, which is parameterized.

Comment: With `[R]` you send a redirect to the browser, i.e. the URL in the browser changes to the URL you don't like. You should rewrite instead of redirect.

Comment: @AhmedGinani sadly it didn't work

Comment: try this `RewriteRule ^film-al-cinema/([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ /index.php?titolo=$1&id=$2 [L]` assuming wp default config.

Comment: RewriteRule ^film-al-cinema/([^/]*)/? /?titolo=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]

Comment: I think we'll need to see your entire `.htaccess` file, with these new directives in context. (You only need the `RewriteRule` directive - one line. You don't need all the others. This should also go at the top of your file.)

Comment: @w3dk Now you see the entire .htaccess file

Comment: Your regex was correct to begin with (although the `(.*)` could be refined as in Deadooshka's comment, ie. `([^/]+)` - but that won't change the behaviour in this example), @Ahmed's suggestion removes the second parameter, so `$2` will always be empty. The `QSA` is also unnecessary, unless you have a query string on the original request that you want to append as well?

Comment: Ok so I put the `^film-al-cinema/(.*)/([0-9]+)$` back?

Comment: What I really need is the second parameter because it is the one that starts the script, with the code of @Deadooshka the page redirects to `/film-al-cinema/` but it doesn't add any variables

Comment: @alessandroduemetri i don't know but try without RewriteBase /

Comment: In the code posted, `RewriteBase` isn't actually being used.

Comment: WP uses its own rewrite system based on server variables, so changing htaccess is confusing thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it works for you (**updated**),

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /film-al-cinema\/\?titolo=([^\s&]+)&id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^film-al-cinema\/$ /film-al-cinema/%1/%2? [R,L]
 RewriteRule ^film-al-cinema/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /film-al-cinema/?titolo=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
```

You should create a backup of your current .htaccess file and then use this code.
If everything works fine add `R=301`in place of `R` in the last line

Comment: It didn't work for me if I go `http://www.pulpcorn.com/film-al-cinema/Guardiani+della+Galassia+Vol.+2/283995` it gives me error 404 instead if I go `http://www.pulpcorn.com/film-al-cinema/?titolo=Guardiani+della+Galassia+Vol.+2&id=283995` it redirect me to film-al-cinema without any variables

Comment: you have added an extra dot `Vol.`, I have to modify my condition for that. wait

Comment: can you please let me know including `-  +  .` what are the special characters there in your url

Comment: @alessandroduemetri I can see that the URL --> http://www.pulpcorn.com/film-al-cinema/?titolo=Ghost+in+the+Shell&id=315837 is redirecting to  http://www.pulpcorn.com/film-al-cinema/Ghost+in+the+Shell/315837   as you wanted after updating the current code, everything will work

Comment: @alessandroduemetri  I have updated the code, and it is working for me, try it and let me know whether it works for you.

Comment: try the code above, after `RewriteBase /` and if it doesn't work there, try it after `. /index.php [L]`

Comment: Thank you for your time, really. I've tried this code and yes i am redirected but I still see the "404 page not found"

Comment: how WordPress is mapping  "pulpcorn.com/film-al-cinema/' has to be questioned now. aren't you able to change things from here --> http://pulpcorn.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php   ?